# TidHttp file download trows Out of memory Exception

Tags: delphi, file, download, delphi-2010, indy

Consider the follow code that downloads a file from internet using Indy components:

```
procedure TForm26.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vFileStream : TStream;
begin
  DeleteFile('C:\test.exe');
  vFileStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\test.exe', fmCreate);
  IdHTTP1.Get('SomeUrl', vFileStream);
  vFileStream.Free;
end;
```

I am getting an Out Of memory exception. What is happening is that besides the fact that I am using `TFileStream`, the bytes that are being written to it do not go directly to the disk, instead, they stay in memory until `get` terminates.

The file I am trying to download is really, really big.

Does anyone knows how to download a big file without getting an out of memory exception?

Delphi 2010 and latest Indy 10 from Indy's SVN.

**EDIT**

That is not a `FileStream` problem. It is a `Indy` problem. Indy is, somehow, caching the file in memory before it writes to the stream.

Comment: In case it matters, what version of Delphi and what version of Indy?

Comment: Delphi 2010 and latest Indy 10 from Indy's SVN.

Comment: What does the code tell you? Does `IdHTTP1.Get` download the entire file to memory before writing to file?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i dont know, i have not looked to indys code.

Comment: `TIdHTTP` downloads the entire file into memory if the data is compressed (Indy does not support streaming decompression for HTTP yet), or if the data is HTML and the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property does not contain the `hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv` flag.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, what does the `hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv` flag do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` downloads the entire file into memory if the data is compressed, or if the data is HTML and the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property does not contain the `hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv` flag.

Indy does not yet support streaming decompression for HTTP (it does for FTP, though), so `TIdHTTP` caches the entire compressed data in memory before it can then decompress it to the file.

Parsing HTML is sometimes needed in cases where the HTML overrides HTTP header values with new values via HTML `<meta>` tags, most importantly the data's Charset value, so `TIdHTTP` can decode the data using the correct charset when the data is being returned to user's code as a `String`.  Enabling the `hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv` flag disables that parsing, and thus any caching of HTML data (unless compression is also used, that is).

Comment: Is there any workaround? Surely there must be since this seems somewhat limiting.

Comment: In order to handle compressed data in the first place, you would have to assign a `TIdZLibCompressorBase`-derived component to the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property. That in turn lets `TIdHTTP` automatically inform the server that compressed responses are supported (unless you are overriding that manually with the `TIdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncodings` property). So the workaround would be to simply remove/disable the Compressor, if in fact that proves to be the actual issue.  I have added tickets to Indy's issue trackers to support streaming decompression in a future release.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that either Netscape or Internet Explorer used to always download the *first* line of an HTML document and, if it contained the dreaded `charset` meta tag, reload the whole page using the new charset. Seems related somehow.

Comment: So, to summarize, the answer would be not to use compression to avoid storing the whole thing in memory?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: `TIdHTTP` does not decode the character data until after it has been downloaded in full, so there is no need to reload the page if there is a charset change.  After the data is downloaded, the `charset` tag is parsed, and if detected then that charset is used for decoding, otherwise the charset specified in the HTTP headers is used instead.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the issue. I was using, on the server side, the Indys `ServeFile` function.

This function checks if a `Content-Type` was specified and if not, it detects automatically the `Content-Type`. The problem was that I did not change the `Content-Type` and it by default was text/html. Changing the content-type made the client write directly to the stream.

I think that the `serveFile` function should always set the correct `Content-Type` to avoid this kind of problems.

On the client side I found out this code that helped me a lot:

```
  LParseHTML := IsContentTypeHtml(AResponse) and Assigned(AResponse.ContentStream) and not (hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv in FOptions);
  LCreateTmpContent := LParseHTML and not (AResponse.ContentStream is TCustomMemoryStream);
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this using the latest SVN snapshot of Indy 10. There is no default `ContentType` assigned yet when the `OnCommandGet` event is fired, so `ServeFile()` should be assigning whatever `ContentType` belongs to the file's extension. The only time `TIdHTTPServer` assigns a default `ContentType` of `'text/html'` is in the `TIdResponseHeaderInfo` constructor, but the `TIdHTTPResponseInfo` constructor resets that back to a blank string afterwards.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to reproduce it afterall.  Seems like it is random, sometimes the default `ContentType` is blank, sometimes it is `text/html`.  I will keep debugging.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. When I saw blank values, I was accidentally looking at `TIdHTTPRequestInfo` instead of `TIdHTTPResponseInfo`. So yes, the default for a **response** is always `text/html`, so I will update `ServeFile()` to account for that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To summarize: this is a bug in the `serveFile` function, right?

Comment: @RafealColucci: no, this is not a bug in `ServeFile()`.  `TIdHTTPServer` allows the user to assign a custom `ContentType` before calling `ServeFile()`.  It is just that `TIdHTTPServer` itself was setting its own non-blank default value, so `ServeFile()` did not know the difference.  I have removed the non-blank default now (and updated `WriteHeader()` to account for that so it can maintain backwards compatibility with user code that was expecting the default value to be sent to clients).

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried downloading the file in parts by setting [`Request.ContentRangeStart`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdEntityHeaderInfo_ContentRangeStart.html) and [`Request.ContentRangeEnd`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdEntityHeaderInfo_ContentRangeEnd.html)?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @RafaelColucci - here http://www.delphigroups.info/2/5/211924.html is example by Remy Lebeau (TeamB)

Comment: @Pol I know it could be a solution, but that is not what I need. If I adopt your solution I will have to change a lot in my code and I cannot believe indys does not write directly to the stream.